# Django: App in subdirectory relative import

Tags: python, django

I'm settings up a Django project following the structure of [this cookiecutter template](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) but I'm having problems with explicit relative imports in my apps.

I'm trying to import my models using `from .model import ModelA` but I'm getting this error from Django:

> RuntimeError: Model class core.models.ModelA doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

My project is structured like this:

```
my_project
  - config
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
  - my_project
    - __init__.py
    - core # this is an app
      - __init__.py
      - models.py
      # remaining app files
  manage.py
```

I have of course put my app in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'my_projects.core.apps.CoreConfig', # my app
]
```

And CoreConfig is setup as:

```
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_project.core'
```

It feels like django is not loading the AppConfig when using explicit relative import.

Everything works perfectly if I change my imports to absolute paths `from my_project.core.models import ModelA`

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:**

Might also be worth mentioning that I've added a few rows to my `manage.py` (as in the cookiecutter template) for adding the `my_project` directory to the sys.path.

```
from django.conf import settings
sys.path.append(os.path.join(settings.ROOT_DIR, 'my_project'))
```

Comment: hi, I just had a same problem. Do you have solved this?

Comment: @baskershu unfortunately no. In the mean time I have decided to use a more standard project structure.

Answer (score 0):

When append urls in `config.urls`, you should use `my_projects.core.urls` instead of `core.urls`. for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
    path("my_projects/", include("my_projects.core.urls", namespace="my_projects")),
] + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

Comment: Haven't had time to test. But I'm pretty sure this won't solve my problem. My problem, as stated in my question, has to do with my models. I have yet to run into problems with urls.